# Why was my question closed as off topic and what can I do to refactor it?

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions

I asked the following question: [How to implement the equivelent to PHP $_Session in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68705782/how-to-implement-the-equivelent-to-php-session-in-node-js), and it was closed for not being on topic.

[image]

This is what it says on the on-topic page

> Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers…
>
> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"

I think my question is within the criteria. Could somebody please help me improve my question?

Comment: FYI, it was closed as _"seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more"_, which doesn't seem to be an accurate close reason in this case. This isn't my area of expertise though, so I won't vote to reopen myself.

Comment: I'd probably have closed it as "need focus" instead since it asked for: 1) how something works, 2) the reasons why 2 frameworks are built differently (i.e. the framework creator's intent, which might or might not be possible to be answered)

Comment: It is *"[equivalent](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/equivalent)"* (not "equivelent").

Comment: Comparing apples and oranges does not tend to lead to good questions. There is no such thing as "sessions in Node", you are asking about ExpressJS which happens to be a third party webserver module for Node. You are free to pick whatever other webserver, perhaps one that does support sessions in a way that is close to how PHP supports it.

Answer (score 6):

[Your question in verbatim has already been asked.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19828686/1079354) Even if you were able to rework this question, it should be closed as this duplicate, which was literally the first result that came up in looking for how to create a session in NodeJS on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate, becuase that only answer how to use it in development not in production as seen here https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session. I asked how and why to use session stores

Comment: Don't tell me that you just *skimmed* that link. Because yes, it says that the **default** session store isn't suitable for production, but it gives you a whole list of production-capable session stores for you to evaluate. There is a difference between an answer being a ready-cooked meal versus the ingredients to cook yourself, but at the end of the day, you at least have the ability to eat.

Comment: Thanks! I did read all of that, now look at my question...... I am asking why we need all that pain in Node and if there is a better solution.... Notice that I even mention redis in my question which is one of the session stores mentioned in that link...

Comment: Asking questions is hard work, and it seems like a waste of time because if the question-writing process is successful, you don't actually ask the question because the process led you to the answer.